# I can't connect my code to my local host webserver from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, webserver

I'm trying to run my code from the terminal to my local host using python3 command but its not running on the server for some reason. Can anyone help?

Here is my code to connect to web server.

```
   from flask import Flask
   from flask import request
   from flask import Response
   import keywordnum

   app_first = Flask(__name__)

@app_first.route("/")

 def key():
    word=request.args.get('word')
    len=keywordnum.count(word)
    reply=str(len)
    r= Response(response=reply, status=200)
    return r

    if__name__=='__main__'
    app_first.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=4000)
```

Comment: Indentation is very important in `python`.  Double-check your code indentation and try running again

Comment: Still giving me the same result. Once i run it in the terminal, I'm expecting a http address that i can copy and paste to see the code on the webserver but its not giving me that.

Comment: Please reformat the code above so we can help you.  You are missing a colon in  `if__name__=='__main__':`.

Comment: Thanks it was not reading the if statement originally but when i deleted and re wrote it, it worked. Not used to the indentation as you said of this python language @jgmh

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation, `python` is strict with it.  The following line

```
if__name__=='__main__'
```

should be rewritten as follows:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
```

Indentation in python allows for a clearer code.